# Why some Android apps don't work with ART?

Tags: android, dalvik

I've tried the new ART jvm developped by google, but I was surprised to see that some apps don't work with this new jvm. There is a list of non-exhaustive compatible apps here : http://www.androidruntime.com/list

There is no difference for the developer, because the jvm acts at runtime. So why some apps don't launch ?

Answer (score 1):

Google made changes in the runtime, for example in the garbage collection. Quite a few things got changed, so here is a small list [ART VERIFYING APP BEHAVIOR](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html) with some Infos.
This might help you. Have fun ;)